# a web application in the cloud as a subfolder of the main company URL

Tags: http, azure, dns, cloud

Is it possible to deploy a web application in the cloud and configure it so that it appears like a subfolder in the company URL.
E.g.

```
www.mycompany.com  //main company web site
www.mycompany.com/products  // hits a web application in the cloud (azure for example)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having in mind it is easier to do with sub-domain and CNAME, I think that what you are looking for is the [IIS URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite).
The following base rules are taken from [this IIS Forum's thread](http://forums.iis.net/t/1168364.aspx), as a similar situation is described and samples rules are given. You may use them as a base:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule">
                <match url="(.+)/(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HostToRedirect:{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="HostToRedirect">
                <add key="domain.com/mail" value="mail.domain.com" />
                <add key="domain.net/mail" value="mail.domain.net" />
            </rewriteMap>
        </rewriteMaps>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

You may also check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632360/how-to-redirect-subfolder-to-query-in-mod-rewrite-for-iis-7-0), as it is providing some guides on the problem you are trying to solve.

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**

This is totally achievable with [URL Rewrite module for IIS](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) in combination with [ARR module](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting). Then you need to set a Reverse Proxy rule that will rewrite all /products requests to the corresponding web app in the cloud. Your rule will look something like that:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(^products)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://myvompany.cloudapp.net/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

You can tweak this later to fit your exact need, but with the above sample I just achieved what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean each and every request first comes to my server and then rewritten or is there any caching involved at the client?

Comment: every request will come to your server first. Then it will server as reverse proxy. You can read the ARR deocumentation on Reverse Proxy, you can cache data from cloud app to the proxy server. As for client caching - client never understands data is comming from different server. All client caching capabilities apply as normal (i.e. content caching - images/js/css) when properly configured on the server side (the application server side - cloudapp).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a DNS expert, but I think you would find it more straightforward to route products.mycompany.com to your Windows Azure web site than a subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

[IIS support redirects](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969%28v=ws.10%29)

I also like the answer from David on making it a web site and use cname to map products.mycompany.com

You could do both.  Redirect www.mycompany.com/products to products.mycompany.com

Comment: A redirect will issue HTTP 301/302 response and the user will actually end up being on http://someservice.cloudapp.net/ instead of staying on http://www.mycompanu.com/products. While with URL rewriting I am almost sure the desired effect can be achieved - the user will work only with http://www.mycompany.com/products, while the underlying requests will be rewritten to http://mycompany.cloudapp.net

Comment: @astaykov OK  Redirect is another option.  As stated can use cname to map products.mycompany.com to someservice.cloudapp.net.

Comment: as David did, but cannot use CNAME for www.mycompany.com/products => mycomany.cloudapp.net
;)
I will play around with UrlRewrite and ARR because I think this is achievable.

Comment: @astaykov For the 3rd time now!  "can use cname to map products.mycompany.com to someservice.cloudapp.net"   If I up vote your answer will you leave me alone?